# Split multiple header into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header, visualization

I have a large csv file. Inside the csv file there are several headers as below.

```
"Level and Distortion",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Ch1 (F)",,"Ch1 (H2)",,"Ch1 (H3)",,"Ch1 (Total)",,"Ch2 (F)",,"Ch2 (H2)",,"Ch2 (H3)",,"Ch2 (Total)",
X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y,X,Y
Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms,Hz,Vrms
20,0.00772013164376534,20,5.60982648239952E-05,20,0.000389709733151927,20,0.011492581958802,20,0.00699792689186063,20,0.000151471712877565,20,0.000389940899485093,20,0.010080448380793
21.1179638886716,0.00747175133180212,21.1179638886716,8.83327496082501E-05,21.1179638886716,0.000426696028852445,21.1179638886716,0.0122462876404656,21.1179638886716,0.00756340531214287,21.1179638886716,0.000181697169530165,21.1179638886716,0.000443499862648762,21.1179638886716,0.0108494276048029
"THD Ratio",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
Hz,%,Hz,%,,,,,,,,,,,,
20,83.009797319554,20,82.1460991930652,,,,,,,,,,,,
21.1179638886716,85.3656629417084,21.1179638886716,82.0338466400102,,,,,,,,,,,,
22.2984199401618,90.6674826441566,22.2984199401618,85.7190774666039,,,,,,,,,,,,
"Reference Waveform",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Ch1,,Ch2,,,,,,,,,,,,,
X,Y,X,Y,,,,,,,,,,,,
s,V,s,V,,,,,,,,,,,,
0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,
2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,2.08333333333333E-05,6.47890208369956E-08,,,,,,,,,,,,
4.16666666666667E-05,5.18304721721536E-07,4.16666666666667E-05,5.18304721721536E-07,,,,,,,,,,,,
6.25E-05,1.74923655865586E-06,6.25E-05,1.74923655865586E-06,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

`Level and Distortion`, `THD Ratio` and `Reference Waveform` are the types of measurements I like to separate. I have to separate some headers in the csv above. For example, when I call variable a, it displays the Levels and Distortion dataframe and its data and if we call variable b it displays the THD ratio dataframe and its data. Does anyone know how to separate them.

The dataframe appears as below.

[image: X]

and also applies to `THD ratio` and `Reference Waveform`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there will always be three header rows, above will be the title of the dataframe (in the first column), and then the values after - and also that you know the names of the headers - you can use the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("so_code.csv", header=None)


# find header rows
df_titles = ["Level and Distortion", "THD Ratio", "Reference Waveform"]
# create groups for each section
groupings = df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains("|".join(df_titles)).cumsum()

# split into new dataframes as dictionary
d = {}
for i, j in df.groupby(groupings):
    # define name of dictionary key as title, and set data of DF as values
    d[j.iloc[0, 0]] = pd.DataFrame(data=j.values[4:, :],
                                   # create MultiIndex from 3 header rows
                                   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                                       j.iloc[1:4, :].ffill(axis=1).values))
    # suggested not to use, but you can set the variables directly (outside of the dictionary)
    globals()[j.iloc[0, 0]] = pd.DataFrame(data=j.values[4:, :],
                                           columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                                               j.iloc[1:4, :].ffill(axis=1).values))
```

`globals()` can be used to find all the defined variables, and `globals()["a"] = 1` will define a variable `a = 1`.  It is suggested not to use this but to define everything explicitly, but if you really don't want to use a dictionary then this is how you can set the variables.

If titles are not known in advance and if there will always be "NA" for all columns after the first for header rows, headers can be found using:

```py
df_titles = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0].to_list()

# split into parts:
# return boolean for whether all columns (2nd to last) contain "NA" for each row
df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1)
# return values in column `0` where above is `True`
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0]
# Add `.to_list()` to convert to a list of values
```

Comment: The type of measurement can change (increase or decrease) how to detect types of measurement without defining the type of measurement.

Comment: That means in the code above to find the headers row, you have to define the names of the measurement types according to the csv that I'm displaying. If the measurement type is different and increases, how do I find the header row without having to define the `df_title` variable

Comment: I have added to my answer with a line of code to replace `df_titles = ...`: `df_titles = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0].to_list()`.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1)` and `df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0]` are placed rows where?

Comment: This is showing what the individual parts of the single line of code does.  You only need that first row, to replace `df_titles = [...]`.

Comment: I have tried but Header and Data do not appear.

Comment: When you run `df_titles = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0].to_list()`, `df_titles` is an empty list?  I am unable to recreate this with the data provided in your question.

Comment: `df_titles` only show the str from the csv file. Some data (number) does not appear if `df_title = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0].to_list()`

Comment: Your assumption is correct, all measurement types will always have three header rows. And each different measurement type will be below the previous measurement.

Comment: When I enter a csv file with different data and measurement types. `df_titles = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1:].isna().all(axis=1), 0].to_list()` can detect the type of measurement type but does not display the data (number).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The measurements are returned as a list, and then this can be used with the rest of the code.  There are no numbers next to the measurement types in your question.